# Bitmap.compress takes too much time ( ~2 seconds )

Tags: android, bitmap, android-bitmap, bitmapimage, bitmapfactory

Bitmap compressing proccess takes too much time. How can I solve that problem ?

in Activity:

```
icon= BitmapFactory.decodeResource(getResources(),R.mipmap.image);
```

in CallBackClass:

```
        synchronized (holder) {
            stream = new ByteArrayOutputStream();
            Log.d("LIFE_CYCLE", "settingImage 1=" + System.currentTimeMillis());
            icon.compress(Bitmap.CompressFormat.PNG, 100, stream);
            Log.d("LIFE_CYCLE", "settingImage 2=" + System.currentTimeMillis());
            byteArray = stream.toByteArray();
            b = BitmapFactory.decodeByteArray(byteArray, 0, byteArray.length);
            if(mWidth<mHeight){
                icon= Bitmap.createScaledBitmap(b, (int)(mWidth*0.75), (int)(mWidth*0.75), false);
            }
            else{
                icon= Bitmap.createScaledBitmap(b, (int)(mHeight*0.75), (int)(mHeight*0.75), false);
            }

            canvas.drawColor(Color.TRANSPARENT, PorterDuff.Mode.CLEAR);
            canvas.drawBitmap(icon, ((mWidth)-icon.getWidth())/2, (mHeight-icon.getHeight())/2, new Paint());
            draw_target(canvas);
        }
```

This line takes ~2 seconds:

```
icon.compress(Bitmap.CompressFormat.PNG, 100, stream);
```

P.S. my image is partly transparent, so I need to use .PNG instead of .JPG

Comment: What exactly are you trying to do ?

Comment: Draw an image ( from mipmap folder ) on a surfaceView

Comment: This code doesn't make sense. You are not store compressed bitmap , so compression is useless. It also use memory unnecessary icon and b take the same amount of memory. Just create scaled from icon. It would be even better to load scaled icon first.

Comment: Selvin, thank you !!! That helped me !!!! Please, write it as an answer and I 'll accept it.

Thank you one more time my friend !

Answer (score 5):

Try to compress using **JPG** instead of **PNG** with **100% quality**. It is getting finished so fast and quality also better. I also faced this problem and fixed with this.

```
icon.compress(Bitmap.CompressFormat.JPEG, 100, stream);
```

Comment: Excellent answer! Cut our per image write down from 4.2 secs to 0.165 seconds (specifically from Bitmap.compress)

Answer (score 0):

try to use bitmap related operations in async task as it is best practice to do heavy operations on background thread/ async task.